# MonoTouch - How to redraw immediately UITableView when datasource is cleared

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, datasource

In MonoTouch, how can i immediately redraw an empty `UITableView` when i cleared its datasource?

```
List<string> ds = new List<string>();

UITableView tbl = new UITableView();
tbl.DataSource = new MyTableViewDataSource(ds);
//And the other parts(datasource class, delegate class etc.) are truely coded when i try to do somewhere at my program, something like
ds.Add("new string");
//it works and table shows new data too, but when i say
ds.Clear();
//it works and clear but table is not redrawn
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you calling `tbl.ReloadData ();` from somewhere ?